# fetchAll() returns array with 0 value (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to bind values into a SQL statement. It appears it is either not binding, or is working and is not returning the needed data for reasons unbeknownst to me. Here is my code:

```
$search_string = 'turkey';

// Gathers the bird ID through searched name
$birdID = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `birds` WHERE `bird_name` LIKE :birdName ;");    
$birdID->execute(array(':birdName' => '%'.$search_string.'%'));  
$returnBirdID = $birdID->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($returnBirdID as $birdID){
    $birdsID[] = $birdID;
}
```

Important to note here is var_dump($birdsID) returns an array as expected.

I have another code block similar to the above that retrieves data based on state abbreviation, e.g. "NY". Leaving it out for brevity (it's almost identical to the above).

```
// Build query for binding.

$sql = "
              SELECT t.state_id,t.bird_id
              FROM table1
              WHERE bird.id = :birdID 
              AND states.id = :statesID ;
          ";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$query->execute(array(':birdID'=>$birdsID,':statesID'=>$statesID));// Think this line may be the problem...
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($results as $getID){
    $getIDs[] = $getID;
}
```

var_dump($getIDs) returns NULL here. I think it may be tied into :birdID'=>$birdsID not accepting $birdsID as a value because all by itself it is an array. But coding it as $birdsID[0] does not work either. Not sure what's up!

Whew... been working on this several hours. If it doesn't make sense, sorry! Brain fried.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Instead, use language, library and method names relevant to your code sample.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: It will turn your `$birdsID` param value into `Array()` or something similar. I doubt this is going to match any records. Assuming `$birdsID` contains at least one entry at index 0, then `$birdsID[0]` should work in the `execute` array

Comment: `$search_string = '%turkey%';` ....`$birdID->execute(array(':birdName' => $search_string)); `

Answer (score 1):

In the PDO tag (info) you will find the correct procedure for using wildcards in parameters.
[image: PDO Tag]

```
$search_string = '%turkey%';

// Gathers the bird ID through searched name
$birdID = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `birds` WHERE `bird_name` LIKE :birdName ;");    
$birdID->execute(array(':birdName' => $search_string));  
$returnBirdID = $birdID->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($returnBirdID as $birdID){
    $birdsID[] = $birdID;
}
```